# What is the reason for UISegmentedControl selected index is remembering (corresponding to indexPath) even cell is reused?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a cell with one `UISegmentedControl` as shown below

[image]

i know the code below is very wrong or its not a good logic

```
//UIViewController
var globalCell = segmentTblCell()  //CUSTOM UITableViewCell Class

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return 10
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = segTblVw.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("segment", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! segmentTblCell

globalCell  = segTblVw.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("segment", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! segmentTblCell  //THIS LINE GIVES VERY STRANGE OUTPUT
return cell
}
```

to my knowledge, that line is only creating new object of cells when invoking `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,  it will create more memory issues..
but **what is the speciality in that line for remembering segment selected index corresponding with cell indexPath?**

and i tried,

- in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, put a `NSLOG` for printing address of `globalCell`, address of `cell` &  `indexPath.row` , and on scrolling, `cell` is reusing, `globalCell` will create new objects
- by adding `UISwitch` to my cell, output is same
- scroll `UITableView` many times, it makes very slow because every time THAT LINE will create many cell
- by adding `UITextField` to my cell, then i found it affect the segment selected index

Can anyone tell me the reason for this???

Reason for asking this question is, McDonal_11's answer in [UISegment value changing when tableview get scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351998/uisegment-value-changing-when-tableview-get-scrolled/32368412?noredirect=1#comment52623361_32368412)

Comment: Re-using a cell doesn't clear its contents.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Does it clear its state? I mean the value that changed by user?

Comment: No, it literally just puts the cell in a queue and it will be pulled out of the queue when you ask the table view for a reusable cell. It doesn't do any sort of clean-up. You have to do everything manually.

Comment: It is complete unclear what you asking for and why you have that globalCell instance?

Comment: @Shoaib i know globalCell instance & that line specified in cellForRowAtIndexPath is very wrong, but why output behaving like this?

Comment: @ShebinKoshy perhaps because… "it doesn't do any sort of clean-up" means that… it doesn't do… **any** sort of clean-up…? including resetting the controls, if any, residing in your cell.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant can u please try that code by removing that line and without removing that line, on both cases, u have to change segment index and scroll tableview for reuse the cells, then u will get what i am telling...

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant as u said , it will not clear the user selection, but when it reuse the user selection also will be affected on reused cells. right?

Answer (score 1):

regarding *to my knowledge, that line is only creating new object of cells when invoking cellForRowAtIndexPath, it will create more memory issues.. but what is the speciality in that line for rememebering segment selected index?*

the cell is only created when there are none in the pool. otherwise, you'll get one that was created before. what you'll want to do is set the cell state each time in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

for example

```
            let cellIdentifier = "Filler"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:indexPath)
            cell.propertyForSegIndex = 1 // or whatever i want it to be
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my question is not that, sorry

Comment: too bad, i dont understand what you're asking.

Comment: can u please try that code by removing that commented line and without removing that line, on both cases, u have to change segment index and scroll tableview for reuse the cells, then u will get what i am telling.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
globalCell  = segTblVw.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("segment", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! segmentTblCell  //THIS LINE GIVES VERY STRANGE OUTPUT
```

Makes no sense, and should not be there. Get rid of it.

Here's the deal: When you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, you get back a cell that was probably used to display other data. It's views will have old values in them. In your case, you'll get cells that have their segmented control set to values other than the first segment.

When you fetch a recycled cell, you always have to fully configure it. Assume all views have old values. (Assume image views are not empty - they contain some other image. Labels contain the wrong text. Segmented controls have the wrong segment selected, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  my cell only have one segmented controls. No other things. As you said  'When you fetch a recycled cell, you always have to fully configure it. Assume all views have old values. (Segmented controls have the wrong segment selected)', in my case, it will not give output like segmented controls have wrong segment selected... it will give correct values as they selected even after reusing the cell. I know, u will not believe. kindly run my code as it is

Comment: You are not making any sense.

Comment: Your cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not setting the segment on your segmented control, so when you dequeue a cell, if that cell was last used with a selected segment other than the first segment, it will show the old value.

Comment: Sir, me too expected that output, but when I executed, I was   really shocked, If you have time, you just execute. Anyway thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Comment: If you want us to try it, post a complete project that shows the behavior.

Comment: can u give me any url to post my project?

Comment: post it to github.com. If you don't have an account you'll have to create one, but it's worth the effort.